# Bubdubbed circle proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

This question involves circles that are bubdubbed. We do not give the exact denition of bubdubbed.
However, we know that if one circle of radius r1 is bubdubbed and another circle of radius r2 is
bubdubbed, then a circle of radius r1 +r2 is bubdubbed. We also know that for all r belongs to {a^3 : a belongs to integers},
a circle of radius r is bubdubbed. Prove that a circle of radius 72 is bubdubbed.

So in this question a universal quantifier is used, so the radius can be from the set {...-8,-1,0,1,8..} can I show that two pairs of values from this set satisfy the conditions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $2^3+4^3=8+64=72$

Comment: Let $S_n$ be the statement "a circle of radius $n$ is buddubbed", we know $S_n$ is true when $n = 1$ and $S_n \implies S_{n+1}$, by induction...

Comment: `the radius can be from the set {...-8,-1,0,1,8..}` What's a circle of radius `-1`?

Comment: You should have extended your set a couple more, then it would be clear as snulty shows.  If you are looking for $72$, you should at least look at all the cubes below $72$.  Try a little harder.

Answer (score 1):

We know that, by the definition of "bubdubbed", any circle with radius $r$ that can be written as the sum of any number of cubes are bubdubbed. In addition, note that

$$1^3+1^3+...+1^3 = r$$

where there are $r$ terms in the summation, so all circles with integer radius are bubdubbed. Thus, the circle with radius $72$ is bubdubbed.

Comment: As I said in my answer, I am not sure that you can add radii that are equal, but this is a good point to make. +1

Comment: I wrote the question as is. I don't know if r1 can be equal to r2. However, my main question is that for this proof can I state two examples from the set? Because a universal quantifier is used and if I prove it for 2 examples then wouldn't it be true for the whole set?

Comment: @NoobMathematician If not, we just start with $r_1=8,r_2=1$ and induct from there.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous when it says "if one circle of radius r1 is bubdubbed and another circle of radius r2 is bubdubbed" is it required that $r1\neq r2$. No matter.  From "for all r belongs to {a^3 : a belongs to integers}, a circle of radius r is bubdubbed" we know that a circle of radius $64 (a=4)$ and a circle of radius $8 (a=2)$ are bubdubbed, so a circle of radius $72=64+8$ is bubdubbed.